# stuck in creating python quizz

Tags: python

hi My code as shown below, when i am trying to execute this code the result always gives me the else clause output, not able to understand where part of code is not working can you help me with it. Even if i type the correct answer still the out put is of else clause

```
quizz = {
    'Question1':{
    'question':'what is the capital of India ',
    'answer':'Delhi\n'
    },
    'Question2':{
    'question':'what is the capital of germany ',
    'answer':'Berlin\n'
    }
}
score = 0
for key,value in quizz.items():
    print(value['question'])
    answer = input('Enter your answer ')

    if answer.lower() == value['answer'].lower():
        print('Thats correct answer')
        score += 1
        print('your score is '+ str(score))
    else:
        print('wrong')
        print('your score is: '  + str(score) )
```

when the user input matches with the answer it should give me the proper output

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns the result without the trailing `'\n'`. Just remove it from the answers in `quizz`, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
quizz = {
    'Question1':{
    'question':'what is the capital of India ',
    'answer':'Delhi\n'
    },
    'Question2':{
    'question':'what is the capital of germany ',
    'answer':'Berlin\n'
    }
```

Because of the \n null character in the aswers, the logic sees it as unequal in the comparison. When you remove them, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend it really works, now able to understand ,

Comment: You are welcome my friend,have a good coding

Answer (score 0):

this code will work, your mistake was using '\n' in the string, i'm assuming you meant for it to create a new line - you don't need to include it :)

```
quizz = {
    'Question1':{
    'question':'what is the capital of India? ',
    'answer':'Delhi'
    },
    'Question2':{
    'question':'what is the capital of Germany? ',
    'answer':'Berlin'
    }
}
score = 0
for key,value in quizz.items():
    print(value['question'])
    answer = input('Enter your answer: ')

    if answer.lower() == value['answer'].lower():
        print('That is the correct answer')
        score += 1
        print('your score is '+ str(score))
    else:
        print('that is the incorrect answer...')
        print('your score is: '  + str(score) )
```

Comment: no worries, if you have any more questions my dms are open, tho im not active much haha

Comment: actually I am new to program so taking small steps to learn, trying to build a logical connection in my mind, sure will make a note of it

Comment: i wish you good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You Have To Remove \n At Answer

So The Code Will Be:

```
quizz = {
    'Question1':{
    'question':'what is the capital of India ',
    'answer':'Delhi'
    },
    'Question2':{
    'question':'whenter code hereat is the capital of germany ',
    'answer':'Berlin'
    }
}
score = 0
for key,value in quizz.items():
    print(value['question'])
    answer = input('Enter your answer ')

    if answer.lower() == value['answer'].lower():
        print('Thats correct answer')
        score += 1
        print('your score is '+ str(score))
    else:
        print('wrong')
        print('your score is: '  + str(score) )
```